# AppleSignIn (with Firebase & Expo) working locally but not on standalone

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, apple-sign-in

I implemented the signinWithApple button on my Expo app, and it's working perfectly locally when i use the `host.exp.Exponent` on `Services ID` in Firebase authentification tab for Apple Sign in.

But when I create a standalone app, and I test it with TestFlight, it doesn't work anymore whether I use `host.exp.Exponent`, nothing, or `my specific app service ID` on `Services ID`.

What am I missing here?

**MY CODE :**

```
handleApple = async () => {
    const csrf = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    const nonce = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 10);

    try {
      const appleCredential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync({
        requestedScopes: [
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.FULL_NAME,
          AppleAuthentication.AppleAuthenticationScope.EMAIL
        ],
        state: csrf,
        nonce: nonce
      });

      const {
        identityToken,

        fullName,
        email
      } = appleCredential;

      if (identityToken) {
        // login with credential
          const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("apple.com");
          const credential = provider.credential({
            idToken: identityToken,
            rawNonce: nonce,

          });

          await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(user => {
          ...
```

**EDIT :**

I managed to make it work by using `my bundle identifier` (which is also my app id) on `the Service ID` field in firebase.

Error code :

> Error: The audience in ID Token [##.app-videos] does not match the expected audience ##.signin.

But now the sign in with Apple on my website breaks.
I manage to make it work when I change the Service Id field to `my specific app service ID` (found in `Identifiers` > `Services IDs`).

So i'm stuck with an app that requires something and a website that requires an other. Why is that?

Should I do something specific when I rebuild my app so that the changes that I made to mu identifiers are taken into account?
I'm using this, is it not enough?

`expo build:ios --clear-provisioning-profile`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but you don't have to be insensitive.
The reason I asked is because i didn't have a way to get the error log from testflight, but I managed to install sentry and to configure it so he sends me console.log.
The problem was that I was using the wrong service id in firebase. It's not the "service ID" like we can read on the documentation, but the actual app ID.

Comment: Hey did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and should solve it in the following way.

You must re-create `GoogleService-info.plist` in the Firebase console with the same bundleId as in the project in Xcode.

Comment: You don't have access to Xcode when you use Expo. So your answer isn't helpful. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just for anyone that comes into this answer, you can configure GoogleService-info.plist in expo, dont be confused by Alis answer. Look at expos property of app.json ios.googleServicesFile